# Android SDK won't work

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to run the Android SDK in Elementary OS 5.0 Juno (based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

This happens whether I use OpenJDK Java 8 or Oracle Java 11. Looking up how to fix it only gave me results from a couple of years ago, I've tried all the suggested fixes and none of those work either! Any ideas?

Comment: So did you try the solutions you did find?

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, they suggested changing to Java 8, which I've tried, and adding Java.se.ee to my JVM options, but neither made a difference